# Something wrong with the svn configuration in centos7

Tags: svn

I tried the following:

```
// install
: yum install httpd subversion mod_dav_svn

// config
: vi /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf

LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule dontdothat_module modules/mod_dontdothat.so

<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/
AuthType Basic
AuthName "SVN Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-accounts
Require valid-user
</Location>

// user add 
: htpasswd -cm /etc/svn-auth-accounts [userid]  // file create
  htpasswd -m /etc/svn-auth-accounts [userid]

// SVN create
: mkdir /var/www/svn
: cd /var/www/svn/
: svnadmin create [repositoryname]
: chown [linuxuser].[linuxuser] [repositoryname]

// chcon
: chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svn/[repositoryname]
: chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/svn/[repositoryname]

// configure firewall
: firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp

// apache(httpd) service start
: systemctl restart httpd.service
: systemctl enable httpd.service
```

And I tried to connect with tortoise svn. But cant connect and show "could not begin a transaction" message.

I gave 777 permissions to the svn repository and it worked fine. However, I think this method is wrong and I raise the question.

Is it right to give permission 777? If not, I would appreciate it if you let me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Permission for repository must be

```
chmod 775 /path/repository/
chown apache:apache /path/repository
```

Change apache:apache to user who run the apache http server (commonly apache or wwwrun)